# Ionic 3 AlertController: Word splits into 2 words on new line

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm showing some message in AlertController. Issue is when there is new line in message, last word is splits into 2 words.

See below image for reference:

**Issue:** 'version' word is splits to 'versi' & 'on'(goes to new line).
**Expected behavior:** if whole word 'version' can't fit into same line, it should display in new line as whole word 'version'.

[image]

Thanks,
Nirav

Answer (score 0):

> Alert text might be set to use word-break.

Add the following CSS in your app.scss file outside the page-app {} tags so that the following CSS gets added outside the root component because AlertController is added to DOM outside the main component

**app.scss file:**

```
page-app{
...
}

.alert-wrapper .alert-message
{
    word-break: keep-all;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try word-break: normal and add ! important

Comment: Are you able to change the css when you inspect it in your browser?

Comment: Can you add the code for presenting the alert? That will give a clearer picture of your implementation and I can reproduce it on my end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206849/discussion-between-nirav-parsana-and-pankaj-sati).

Comment: I tried to create new project and found issue is because of [Ionic translate](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/ng2-translate/). See my outputs [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/alertcontroller-word-splits-into-2-words-on-new-line/182353/2).